# Is it possible to control-drag in Xcode with a trackpad and tap-to-click?

Tags: xcode, trackpad

The interface builder in Xcode uses control-drag as a general gesture for wiring up outlets and object connections. But as a tap-to-click user, I'd prefer to avoid having to activate the physical trackpad switch. Has anyone figured out a way to make this work?

My normal drag gesture is three-finger-drag, but control-three-finger-drag doesn't activate the control-drag features in Xcode. Nor have I been able to make it work by experimenting with other combos in Xcode.

The control-drag gesture does work just fine if you use the physical switch.

My trackpad configuration is simple: every checkbox in the Trackpad preferences is checked.

Comment: would be interested to know how this turns out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out [this app](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/setting-up-custom-trackpad-gestures-on-your-mac--mac-47668)

one of the screen shots shows you can 'ctrl left click', which you can apply to a '3 finger tap' for example. It should be as simple as 3 finger tapping, holding, and dragging to make a connection.

Hope that works!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually, I use a similar touchpad enhancements app (BetterTouchTool) that doesn't seem to have any dragging-related features. But your mention of MagicPrefs reminded me to verify that BTT isn't interfering with Xcode, and by gosh it is. With BTT turned off, you can in fact control-tripple-finger drag in Xcode. I don't have any triple-finger gestures enabled in BTT, so I assume this is some sort of BTT issue; I'll report it there.